# При создании контактной формы на html+php+js все работает кроме одного поля

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-form

помогите решить проблему! Уже всю голову сломал что не так. Есть контактная форма. прописана на странице контактов :

```html
<div class="main-contact-form">
  <div id="message"></div>
  <form id="maincontact_form" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          <input class="form-control" id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="ВАШЕ ФИО*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          <input class="form-control" id="contact_email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          <input class="form-control" id="contact_phone" type="text" placeholder="ТЕЛЕФОН*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
          <input class="form-control" id="contact_subject" type="text" placeholder="ТЕМА ПИСЬМА">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="contact_message" placeholder="СООБЩЕНИЕ*"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

За ее отправку отвечает файл php и js.

Код из файла PHP

```html
<?php 

function sh_set( $var, $key )
{
 if( isset( $var[$key] ) ) return $var[$key];
 
}
 $contact_to = 'mail@am-ch.ru';
 include('validation.php');
 $validation = new SH_Validation;
 
 if( !count( $_POST ) ) return;
 
 
  /** set validation rules for contact form */
  $validation->set_rules('contact_name','<strong>'.'Name'.'</strong>', 'required|min_length[2]|max_lenth[30]');
  
  //$validation->set_rules('aplus_l_name','<strong>'.'Last Name'.'</strong>', 'required|min_length[4]|max_lenth[30]');
  $validation->set_rules('contact_email','<strong>'.'Email'.'</strong>', 'required|valid_email');
  
  $validation->set_rules('contact_phone','<strong>'.'Phone'.'</strong>', 'min_length[10]');
  $validation->set_rules('contact_subject','<strong>'.'Subject'.'</strong>', 'min_length[2]');
  
  $validation->set_rules('contact_message','<strong>'.'Message'.'</strong>', 'required|min_length[2]');
  
  $messages = '';

  if($validation->run() !== FALSE && empty($validation->_error_array))
  {
   $name = $validation->post('contact_name');
   $email = $validation->post('contact_email');
   
   $message = "Имя: ".$name."\r\n";
   $message .= "\r\n"."Телефон: ".$validation->post('contact_phone')."\r\n";
   $message .= "\r\n"."Тема: ".sh_set( $_POST, 'contact_subject')."\r\n";
   
   $message .= "\r\n"."Сообщение:  ".$validation->post('contact_message'); 
 
   //$contact_to = ( sh_set($settings, 'contact_email') ) ? sh_set($settings, 'contact_email') : get_option('admin_email');
 
   $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
   mail($contact_to, 'Contact Us Message', $message, $headers);
 
   //$message = sh_set($settings, 'success_message') ? $settings['success_message'] : sprintf( __('Thank you <strong>%s</strong> for using our Contact form! Your email was successfully sent and we will be in touch with you soon.',SH_NAME), $name);
 
   //$messages = '<div class="alert alert-success">'.'SUCCESS! '.$message.'</div>';
   echo "<fieldset>";
   echo "<div id='success_page' class='alert alert-success'>";
   echo "<h3>".'Email успешно отправлен.'."</h3>";
   echo "<p>".sprintf("Спасибо <strong>%s</strong>, Ваше сообщение успешно отправленно.", $name)."</p>";
   echo "</div>";
   echo "</fieldset>";
   exit;
  
  }else
  {
 
    if( is_array( $validation->_error_array ) )
    {

     foreach( $validation->_error_array as $msg )
     {
      $messages .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.'Упс! Возникла ошибка! Попробуйте еще раз, или свяжитесь с нами по телефону!'.$msg.'</div>';
     }
   }
 
  }
 
  echo $messages;exit;
```

Код из файла скрипта на JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


      $('#maincontact_form').on('submit', function() {

            var action = $(this).attr('action');
            $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {
              $('#message').hide();

              $('#submit_btn')
                .after('<img src="img/AjaxLoader.gif" class="loader" />')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

              $.ajax({
                url: 'contact.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                  contact_name: $('#contact_name').val(),
                  contact_email: $('#contact_email').val(),
                  contact_phone: $('#contact_phone').val(),
                  contact_subject: $('#contact_subject').val(),
                  contact_message: $('#contact_message').val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                  $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                  $('#maincontact_form img.loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                  });
                  $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
                  if (data.match('success') != null) $('#maincontact_form').slideUp('slow');
                }
              });

            });

            return false;
```

В итоге все работает, сообщение на почту доставляется, НО! Не "цепляется" номер телефона из формы, приходит сообщение, а вместо телефона просто пустая строка! Пробовал сделать поле "телефон" обязательным к заполнению, в итоге при отправке формы при правильно указанном номере вылетает ошибка, что поле телефон обязательно для заполнения, те как будто поле вообще не заполнено. Меня уже не хватает на поиски в гугле, прочитал овермного статей но ответ так и не нашел! Помогите! Буду благодарен любому совету!

Comment: В `contact_phone` буква 'c' может быть в одном месте русской, а в другой латинской. А это две большие разницы.

Comment: @ArchDemon Не помогло( препрописал все вручную заново во всех файлах, все тоже самое, все поля отправляются, телефон нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать тег `<input type="tel">`, и проверить `min_length[10]`, может не проходит проверку

Comment: Роман! Спасибо! Изменение тега помогло, но вообще странно, до этого тоже менял на данный тег и не получилось, но по скольку менял сразу много чего для тестирования, могло что то другое не давать) в отчаинии разбить ноут о стену написал сюда) все равно спасибо вам) возможно в совокупности с изменением по предыдущим комментариям помогло!